# Ignoring remote commits, only push local

Tags: git

I made some changes to a branch and pushed the commits accidentally (there were file changes included that were not supposed to be there). And I tried to `git revert` the commit but the changes to the files that needed to be change were not.

So I decided to delete the branch itself through Stash, and remake the branch again. However, the branch now keeps telling me

```
Switched to branch 'branch1'
Your branch is behind 'origin/branch1' by n commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

But I want to ignore those n commits and start fresh, is there a way I can just ignore those commits and just push my fresh/completely new commits from the new local?

Comment: if you are sure that your local branch is proper and want to override remote commits in that branch, then you need force push. `git push -f origin branch1`

Comment: @ShashwatKumar do I need `origin/branch1` or git will know branch1 local points to origin/branch1?

Comment: Git will know automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need git push -f

For example:

> git push -f origin branch1

This will force it to override the git logs